# add pandas data to the top of an existing csv file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv

I know how to add pandas data to an existing file:

```
df.to_csv('my_csv.csv', mode='a', header=False)
```

It seems as though the new data is appended to the **bottom** of the CSV file.
I need the new rows of data to go at the **top** of the CSV file (ordered by data & time).

One solution, for example, is to download the existing CSV into a Dataframe and then append the new rows of data into the DataFrame and save the modified DataFrame back to CSV, but this seems to be cumbersome and would like to avoid this if possible.

I would ideally be looking for something like this (if it exists):

```
df.to_csv('my_csv.csv', mode='a', header=False, put_data_at_top=True)
```

Question:
Is there a (quick and efficient or standard pythonic) way to add the new data to the top of the CSV file ?

(the existing csv file top row has headers)

Comment: i think you'll need to read your file into memory concat it, then overwrite it.

Comment: So far the best option is the reverse the order of the data (sorted by date and time) and append to the bottom.

Comment: There is no appending mode to the top of the file because it is not supported by the operating systems. Indeed, fast appending to the end is possible because this is something usual and mostly supported by current filesystem. While fast appending to the top of a file could theoretically be supported, it was too uncommon to be implemented in the libc, and so now to all derived libraries/softwares including Python packages and more specifically Pandas.